# Java Exelsior error when using on other computers

Tags: java

I am using [Excelsior](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) to make my jar executable into a .exe and I'm getting errors when putting the exe and folder contents on another computer. The program packs what looks like the java run time into a folder called 'rt'. The .exe runs fine on my own computer but when I try on others I get this error:

```
Invalid Excelsior JRE directory "C:\ programFolder\rt": path canonicalization failded
```

Anyone know what could cause this error or if you have used Excelsior could you help me out with this? I have posted on their forums but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are copying the EXE file that was processed by the packager (JetPackII), not the EXE emitted by the compiler?

Also make sure to install the latest updates (for Excelsior JET 9 it is Maintenance Pack 2 as of today.)